# karma-init fails on Windows 10 with Node.js 7.1.0 x64

Tags: node.js, npm, jasmine

After installing succesfully the following node packages:

- karma
- karma-jasmine
- karma-chrome-launcher
- jasmine-core

I get the following error when executing `karma-init`:

```
C:\Projects\SocialMeal>karma init
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

    Error: write EINVAL
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at WriteStream.Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:715:26)
    at WriteStream.Socket._write (net.js:734:8)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:334:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:320:5)
    at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:247:11)
    at WriteStream.Socket.write (net.js:661:40)
    at Interface._writeToOutput (readline.js:256:17)
    at Interface._insertString (readline.js:406:12)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:933:18)
    at Interface.write (readline.js:352:24)
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I found it.

It seems like an Node.js 7.1.0 issue. It happens with newer Node.js versions (<7.0.0) as posted here:

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/9542

Until they fix this issue you need to uninstall your node.js and install an older version (e.g.: 6.9.1) in order to make ir work.